# Create table as Select, then Update statement with JOIN in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using Oracle HR database. 
I was wondering why the following query isn't working:

```
create table ecopy 
as select *
from employees;

create table dcopy
as select *
from departments;

UPDATE (select d.location_id, e.salary 
from ecopy e inner join dcopy d 
on e.department_id=d.department_id)
set salary = salary+1 
where location_id = 1800
```

> SQL Error: ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key->preserved table

While the this one, on the origin tables is doing it's job:

```
UPDATE (select d.location_id, e.salary 
from employees e inner join departments d 
on e.department_id=d.department_id)
set salary = salary+1 
where location_id = 1800
```

Could anyone explain it to me?

Comment: Probably because the `create table as` lacks constraints, such as primary key constraints and unique key constraints.

Comment: i think the same but i didn't expect it would be so required while the values are ok

Comment: If you did think the same, you could have tried an experiment: on your **copy** tables, add the primary key constraint on `dcopy.department_id` and try the `update` statement again. You would have seen that it would go through as expected. (Really a unique constraint or a unique index on that column would suffice; obviously "primary key" is stronger so that would suffice too.) Then you ask the very reasonable question, "*why*"? The answer is that the error you are seeing is a *compilation* error - it is not thrown at runtime, but earlier.

Comment: What is happening is that in the process of parsing the `update` statement, the parser checks existing constraints - it does **not** inspect the actual data to see that there are no duplicates (even without a unique constraint). At compile time, before seeing the data, Oracle either knows that that column is unique, or it doesn't. Without a constraint or an index, it doesn't, so you get that compile-time error.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the explanation:

In your real life your relation supported by keys - reference constraint

```
employee.department_id(MANY) = departments.department_id(ONE)
```

In the case of `UPDATE` with `JOIN`, you can update only columns in your "MANY" table and only if they have real reference.

Your `Create as select. . .` tables definitely don't have these references, hence Oracle optimizer throws this error.

Here are some references
[Reference 1](https://it.toolbox.com/question/ora-01779-cannot-modify-a-column-which-maps-to-a-non-key-preserved-table-121014)
[Reference 2](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:9536728300346467860)